# npm install gives MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using a 2017 mac and `npm install` is always quick and easy. Today I notice that its keep throwing me below error when I try to do `npm install` My system was working fine and I did not see any issues anywhere.

```
MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Node and npm version:

`node: v20.9.0`
`npm: 10.1.0`